# merging image in android

Tags: android

I want to merge two different images of two different size and create a single image out of it and save it in sdcard.The image format what i am using is jpg.Is it possible to create merged image as jpg??

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "merge"? You can load your two images as Bitmap objects, create a new Bitmap and an accompanying Canvas, draw your two images into the new Bitmap and then save it as a jpg using:

```
bitmap.compress(
    CompressFormat.JPEG,
    95, // or whatever compression ratio you want
    new FileOutputStream("/some/location/image.jpg")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.imagemerging;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button btnLoadImage1, btnLoadImage2;
 TextView textSource1, textSource2;
 Button btnProcessing;
 ImageView imageResult;

 final int RQS_IMAGE1 = 1;
 final int RQS_IMAGE2 = 2;

 Uri source1, source2;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  btnLoadImage1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage1);
  btnLoadImage2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadimage2);
  textSource1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sourceuri1);
  textSource2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sourceuri2);
  btnProcessing = (Button)findViewById(R.id.processing);
  imageResult = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.result);

  btnLoadImage1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
      android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_IMAGE1);
   }});

  btnLoadImage2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
      android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_IMAGE2);
   }});

  btnProcessing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    if(source1 != null && source2 != null){
     Bitmap processedBitmap = ProcessingBitmap();
     if(processedBitmap != null){
      imageResult.setImageBitmap(processedBitmap);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "Done", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "Upload The Image", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    }else{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
       "Select both image!", 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

   }});
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
   switch (requestCode){
   case RQS_IMAGE1:
    source1 = data.getData();
    textSource1.setText(source1.toString());
    break;
   case RQS_IMAGE2:
    source2 = data.getData();
    textSource2.setText(source2.toString());
    break;
   }
  }
 }

 private Bitmap ProcessingBitmap(){
  Bitmap bm1 = null;
  Bitmap bm2 =  null;
  Bitmap newBitmap = null;

  try {
   bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
     getContentResolver().openInputStream(source1));
   bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
     getContentResolver().openInputStream(source2));

   int w;
   if(bm1.getWidth() >= bm2.getWidth()){
    w = bm1.getWidth();
   }else{
    w = bm2.getWidth();
   }

   int h;
   if(bm1.getHeight() >= bm2.getHeight()){
    h = bm1.getHeight();
   }else{
    h = bm2.getHeight();
   }

   Config config = bm1.getConfig();
   if(config == null){
    config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
   }

   newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, config);
   Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

   newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, null);

   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setAlpha(128);
   newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm2, 0, 0, paint);

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return newBitmap;
 }

}


//Layout


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.imagemerging.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadimage1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttontext_loadimage1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sourceuri1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadimage2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttontext_loadimage2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sourceuri2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/processing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/buttontext_processing" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```